# How to add placeholder image when the camera is close of subscriber ( using Vonage Opentok in flutter )

Tags: flutter, dart, opentok, vonage

I am using Vonage Opentok in flutter. When the call starts and during the call, subscriber closed its camera a black screen will be shows.

i want that when the subscriber close its camera an placeholder image will be shown.
I tried putting a background image but it wont work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.